# Specific actionscript functions for a c++ progammer

Tags: c++, actionscript-3, actionscript

I am coming from the C++ world and i want to do some simple stuff with Actionscript 3.0.
Have search around this site and google and haven't found a universally accepted way to do so. I will give you the C++ code of the analogous of what I am trying to do in Actionscript 3.0.

**Pass by reference:**

```
void somefunction (string &passvariable);
```

**Create instance of, deep copy:**

```
string something;
string somethingelse;
something = "randomtext";
somethingelse = something;
```

Answer (score 4):

***Pass by reference***

**Every *object* is passed by reference**. As far as I know, there are no explicit `& address of` or `* dereference` operators. Actionscript is a higher level language than that.

Primitive types (and Strings are primitive - see link) are Immutable in Actionscript, so pass by value / pass by reference are [effectively the same.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9c.html)

***Deep Copy / Instance of***

**ObjectUtil.clone / ObjectUtil.copy** will create **sometimes-deep** copies of Objects, *if you're working in Flex*. I usually don't rely on it for anything deep, however. In most cases you will want to create your own **clone** style method to create a deep copy.

A generic, flexible **clone** method can be found [here](http://www.rozengain.com/blog/2009/02/10/easy-deep-clone-method-for-actionscript-30/)

Comment: You can't use String as an out argument, though, because it is immutable?

Comment: That's incorrect, @visitor. Immutable means cannot be changed. So any time you do any String manipulation, you create **new** Strings. Coming from a C++ contect, I thought the author may be interested in that.

Comment: In case my comment was not clear, references to those **new** Strings can still be passed around, as well as references to the original String you manipulated (in its original form).

Comment: Still not clear. Is it similar to Python, where you cannot expect changes done to a string argument to affect the caller: http://ideone.com/25ec8 ? (Don't have Actionscript available at the moment.)

Comment: @visitor Yes. The String is immutable. So if you have a `var s:String = "Hello"`, and later `var str:String = s.substring(0,1)`, `trace(s)` will display "Hello" and `trace(str)` will display "H".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found 2 useful ifo. All primitive types are passed by copying and most of the other types are passed by reference but i found adobes manual online not so well defined about this subject. Objectutil is part of the mx package which is only available in Flex.

Comment: @Peter thanks! I always lose track of what I've just gotten used to having in Flex, I'll add a comment there.

Answer (score 0):

The rules for pass as reference are different for simple data types like string and number than they are for objects and complex data types. 
If you are passing a string to a function, it creates a copy, leaving the original untouched. 
So to pass by reference, try creating an object:

```
var str:Object = {string:"foo"};
        passByref(str);
        trace(str.string);

    private function passByref(str:Object):void 
    {
        str.string = str.string + "bar";
        trace("inside", str);
    }
```

As for deep object cloning, this works great:

```
package
{
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    public class DeepCopyUtil
    {
        public static function clone (source : Object) : *
        {
            var array : ByteArray = new ByteArray ();

            array.writeObject (source);
            array.position = 0;

            return array.readObject ();
        }

    }
}
```

Credit where credit is due:
http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_How_to_create_deep_copies_of_objects_and_arrays-19261.html

Answer (score -2):

In Actionscript you have to define all things with function, var or const.
You should define the (return type) after the variable name, like var:String

**Creating a function**

```
function someFunction (var:String):void
{

}
```

**Copy a string**

```
var something:String;
var somethingElse:String;
something = "randomtext";
somethingelse = something;
```

Comment: -1 not sure that you understand what he means by deep copy, although in this case your solution is great

Comment: When you alter the variable 'somethingelse' in this case, the variable 'something' would not be changed. So how much deeper do you want to copy? In cases of numbers, strings this works exactly like this. In case of Object or DisplayObjects or dates (+some more) this is different ofcourse and you'll need a copy objects with some kind of ObjectUtil. I don't know how this works in c++ so sorry about that.